# Get user's groups via Javascript in Atlasian Confluence

Tags: javascript, confluence

Is it possible to get the groups the currently logged in user belongs to in Atlasian Confluence using Javasrcipt stored in the "Custom HTML"?

I can get the currently logged in user as follows but cant find an example for getting the user's groups:

```
function getCurrentUserName(){
    var user;
    AJS.$.ajax({
        url: "/rest/gadget/1.0/currentUser",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) { user = data.username; }
    });
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access that in JavaScript without a little server side help...

Edit the **Main Layout** in **Confluence Admin | Look And Feel | Layouts**

Add this before the `</head>` tag:

```
#if($action.authenticatedUser)
    #set($groupNames = $userAccessor.getGroupNames($action.authenticatedUser))
    <meta name="ajs-group-names-csv" content=",#foreach($group in $groupNames)$group,#end">
#end
```

In your Javascript, you'll now be able to access the groups using `AJS.Meta.get('group-names-csv')`

This will return something like:

```
",confluence-administrators,confluence-users,"
```

So, to get an array of group names and check if the user is an admin:

```
const groupNamesCsv = AJS.Meta.get('group-names-csv');
const groupNames = groupNamesCsv.split(',').filter(i => i !== '');

const userIsAdmin = groupNames.includes('confluence-administrators');

// or directly test for a group name
// const userIsAdmin = groupNamesCsv.includes(',confluence-administrators,'); // as all group names are surrounded by commas
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by dvdsmpsn worked for me. However, I had to use (AJS.Meta.get('group-names-csv').includes("text123")) in the Custom HTML > end of BODY in Confluence.